# What is the difference between a package and container?

Tags: docker, npm, kubernetes, package, containers

GitHub recently released a container registry alongside their package registry. What is the difference? When would it be better to use one or the other? Do we need both?

Comment: For more context; Node.js is typically my only dependency that's not handled by NPM, and I use serverless functions so I am never running more than one application at a time. Is there any reason for me to consider using containers?

Answer (score 2):

Packages are generally simple: they are essentially an archive (i.e. zip file) that contains contents (code libraries, application executables, etc.) and a manifest file (json document, xml file, etc) that describes those contents with a package name and version number (at a minimum).
ie:- npm,pip and composer packages.

Container images are also simple, but they're more like an archive (i.e. a zip file) than a package.
ie:- nginx, redis etc

Verdict:- if some libs repetitively used in any project then we can create package and use in project .while for all project based dependencies we need to choose container to run this. Yes we need both.

Comment: So they are both a collection of files (you said both are like zip files) ones just smaller than the other? I don't see why that necessitates that we need both. I build Node.js apps without containers. Why should I use containers, and when shouldn't I?

Comment: well to run application in isolation mode , you need container like docker.modern devops standards required container based structure you can orchestrate as well with help of kubernetes.

Comment: Why would you want to run an application in isolation mode? What if you are using AWS Lambdas, where you are only running one application at a time?

Comment: because it can conflict to existing other running apps . you can check https://medium.com/swlh/what-exactly-is-docker-1dd62e1fde38

Comment: So if you're only running one application, or developing one application you don't need containers?

Comment: then you can yes , but for heavy traffic based application needs containers so it can be orchestrate to scale up app.

Answer (score 1):

After debating this with a Docker-using friend for a while I think I've found a satisfactory explanation:

- Packages are for modules of code which are compiled together into an
  Application.
- Containers are for Applications which are compiled together into a
  Server.

This is a bit confused by the fact that a Package can contain a standalone Applications, and Containers will often use package managers like Apt to install these applications. I feel like this is an abuse of package management due to a legacy where we didn't have Containers. Eventually I would expect most Applications will be delivered in Container form.